# For what vs. what ... for

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of these sentences is correct / more common / formal?

> **For what** did he win a Nobel Prize?
>
> **What** did he win a Nobel Prize **for**?

Comment: To avoid the preposition _for_, one could ask, "How did he win his Nobel Prize?"

Comment: The *for what* version is less common.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "What for?" and "For what?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22937/what-is-the-difference-between-what-for-and-for-what)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For what did he win a Nobel Prize?

Very correct, very formal.

> What did he win a Nobel Prize for?

More colloquial. Also very dependent on context &/or emphasis.

Taken at face value, & also when written, it asks the same question as the first version… but with emphasis on *he* it could indicate the speaker is wondering why the Nobel committee  thought he was deserving of an award.

Comment: Thanks, yes, they are both supposed to mean the same thing.

Comment: The distorted meaning in the second version is simply that the exact wording could be used to ask two questions; very dependant on context & emphasis. I often look for unintentional misconceptions in sentences - my sense of humour depends on them ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - do you think if this sentence is correct - What did he win a Nobel prize in?

Comment: @Leo - both questions are correct, but they mean different things. The answer to: _What did in win a Nobel Prize in?_ would be something like, "Economics," or, "Physics." The answer to: _What did he win a Nobel Prize for?_ is something like, "For his advances in game theory," or, "For his discovery of a new subatomic particle."

Comment: @J.R.- thanks. that was very useful for me to know