# Identify people in a photo

Tags: questions

Look at [this quiz](http://snwmf.com/phorum/read.php?1,261748). Is it correct to say:

> Whose photo is this?

As far as I know there's a difference between

> This is a photo of David. (=You can see David in the photo.)

and

> This is David's photo. (=The photo belongs to David, but you can see
>   Mike in it.)

So the right question is

> Who is this a photo of?

Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Related (but I don't think it is a duplicate): [What this photograph is of: Why does it sound weird?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/59297/9161)

Comment: *Who is this a photo of?* is idiomatic and it means "Who is this person in the picture?"

Answer (score 2):

> Who is this photo of?
>   Who's in this photo?
>   This is a photo of whom?

all ask who is in the photo unambiguously.

> Whose photo is this?

is ambiguous since it can mean either "to whom does this photo belong" or "who is in the photo".

> This is a photo of David.

is unambiguous.

> This is David's photo.

is ambiguous since it can mean either the photo belongs to David, or the picture is of David

> This is David's photo when he was 3 years old.