# Is it true that questions in English cannot end on a preposition?

Tags: grammar-myths

Is it true that questions in English cannot end on a preposition?

Somebody told me that, but the more I continue on my English tour the more I run into suspicions here.

Are such questions like:

> Where did she run **to**?
>
> What did he look **at**?

really wrong?!

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: they are correct

Comment: @SovereignSun - I am talking about questions in English that end on a preposition - just like the one you asked.

Comment: @brilliant That's exactly why I asked. If that doesn't irritate you then you are free to use prepositions at the end of a sentence. It is absolutely correct.

Comment: when you want to use a phrasal verb in a question , the preposition is always placed at the end .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is ending a sentence with a preposition acceptable?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/611/is-ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition-acceptable) Also [Sentence that finishes with prepositions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85229/sentence-that-finishes-with-prepositions)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - Yes, it does! Thank you!