# Question about relative pronouns and clauses

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

My friend wants to share some sugar with me. I need a container for it. What should I say in the following situations?

1. I'll go and look for something to put it in.
2. I'll go and look for something **that/what/where** I can put it in.

If I'm trying to cut the butter can I say:

1. I'm looking for something to cut the butter.
2. I'm looking for something to cut the butter **with**.
3. I'm looking for something **that/what/which** I can cut the butter **with**.

Comment: Sugar: 1. Yes 2. Yes, (that). Butter: 1. Yes (hmmm...) 2. Yes (better) 3. Yes (that).

Comment: I would go with butter 1=best and 2=ok. The final "with" being unnecessary. All the butter 3 options are long winded. You could say "I'm looking for something with which I can cut the butter".

Comment: @AdrianHHH The 'with which' version is formally correct, but would sound a bit high-falutin for everyday conversation!

Comment: @KateBunting agreed, hence I wrote 1=best plus I wanted to say more about the 3.

Comment: In butter situation is option 3 grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, it is grammatically correct (as @KateBunting mentioned) but most speakers would not say it in everyday speech.

Comment: This brings up the old debate about whether or not we can end a sentence with a preposition - see [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/611/is-ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition-acceptable). As I noted, Adrian's version is 'correct', but in practice most speakers would say "I'm looking for something [that] I can cut the butter with" (or your sentence 2.).